# How to get first and last number couples from array/dataframe by skipping NaN

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Given a list or data frame (matter of speed):

```
data = 

array([[45,  7, 43,6,nan, nan],
       [44,  6, 42,5,nan,nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, nan,nan,nan],
       [41,  5, 48,23,21,34],
       [46,  4, 47,22,nan,nan],
       [nan, nan, nan,nan,nan,nan]])
```

for every row I want to get first and last `2` numbers **by skipping the NaN's** and store them.

Desired output:

```
final_data = ([45,7, 35,6],
              [first 2 number, last 2 numbers]
              [first 2 number, last 2 numbers]
              [first 2 number, last 2 numbers]
              [first 2 number, last 2 numbers])
```

Comment: Reproducible sample of data?

Comment: @pissall Question edited

Comment: please share the expected output for the updated example too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using numpy, you can leverage the [logical not operator](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_not.html) and [np.isnan()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html).

Here a quick example:

```
>>> x = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,np.nan,np.nan]])
>>> for a in x:
...     r = a[~np.isnan(a)]
...     print(r[:2],r[-2:])
...
[1. 2.] [4. 5.]
[1. 2.] [2. 3.]
```

Using your data:

```
>>> x
array([[45.,  7., 43.,  6., nan, nan],
       [44.,  6., 42.,  5., nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [41.,  5., 48., 23., 21., 34.],
       [46.,  4., 47., 22., nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]])
```

Then

```
final_data = [] 

for a in x:   
    r = a[~np.isnan(a)] 
    if len(r): #skip empty arrays
        res = (r[:2],r[-2:])
    final_data.append(res)

pd.DataFrame(final_data)

    [45.  7.] [43.  6.]
    [44.  6.] [42.  5.]
    [41.  5.] [21. 34.]
    [46.  4.] [47. 22.]
```